# Is this branch from the blueberry root stock?

Tags: blueberries, invasive

So I have about 6 blueberry plants and last summer (which was very very dry, drought for about two months) there were woody plants coming up at the bases of about 4 of them. They're not the same leaves as the blueberry plants and this year their flowers aren't at all the same. Are they suckers from root stock? Are they something else?

I'm in Buffalo, NY

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is not from your blueberry, that's a kind of [willow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willow) (salix).

(I'll do some more research and post possible candidates for a better id later.)